# Check if mysql is using multithreading?

Tags: centos, mysql, central-processing-unit, multi-threading

When I check the processes/active tasks on centos using the `top` command, when using SSH.
I only see 1 mysql process. Does this mean that it is only using one cpu core out of my 4 cpu  cores?

Comment: `top` doesn't show threads, it shows processes.

Comment: @EEAA so, your suggestion is....

Answer (score 1):

Mysql is definitely a multithreaded application, and has no option to 'disable multithreading', whatever that would mean. A tool like htop will show you individual threads, as will looking in `/proc/`:

```
dennis@lightning:~$ ls  /proc/$(pidof mysqld)/task/ | wc -l
17
```

The `task/` directory for a process contains one entry per thread. Mysql on this bix is currently thus using 17 threads.

Comment: htop: command not found

Comment: @user8005 - so *install* it.

Comment: htop only shows one process.

Comment: Does this mean that it is only using one cpu core out of my 4 cpu  cores?

Comment: That means your htop is behaving differently than mine. How many subdirs are there in /proc/$(pidof mysqld)/task ?